# React Native - How to select an Image then send to another screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm new to coding and I have a question on how can you select an image from an array and send it to another page in the image source.

I dont know if that is properly worded but this has been bothering for the last 4 days.

I'll take any suggestions at all I want to learn from you.

```
import React, {Component,} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, Platform, StatusBar, Image, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { Icon, Button, Container, Header, Content, Left, Right, Body } from 'native-base';
import  Ionicons  from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';


import Settings from './settings';
import homescreen from './homescreen';
import Saved from './bookmarkscreen';
import IndivPhoto from './indivphoto';


var gold = [
    require('../../images/pc1.jpg'),
    require('../../images/pc3.jpg'),
    require('../../images/pc4.jpg'),
    require('../../images/pc5.jpg'),
    require('../../images/pc6.jpg'),
    require('../../images/pc7.jpg'),
    require('../../images/pc8.jpg'),
    require('../../images/storm.png'),
    require('../../images/vanguard.png'),
    require('../../images/vanguard2.png'),
]
```

**This is the array of images.**

```
var {width,height} = Dimensions.get('window')
export default class Profile extends React.Component {
constructor(props)
{
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        activeIndex: 0, 
    }
}
segmentClicked = (index) => {
    this.setState({
        activeIndex: index
    })
}

renderSectionOne = () => {
    return gold.map((image,index)=>{
        return(
        <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={() =>  this.props.navigation.navigate('IndivPhoto')}>
            <View key={index} style={[ {width:(width)/3}, {height:(width)/3},
            { marginBottom: 2 },
             index % 3 !==0 ? {paddingLeft: 2 }: {paddingLeft: 0 }
             ]}>
                <Image  
                    resizeMethod="resize" 
                    style={{flex:1, width: undefined, height: undefined}}
                    source={image}
                />
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    })
}
```

This is the render method for the images in var gold. What i want to know is how can i select an individual image from the map render section and send it to another screen.

class IndivPhoto extends React.Component {
 constructor(props)
    {
        super(props)

```
    this.state = {
        activeIndex: 0
    }
}
 render() {
     return(
        <ScrollView>
            <Header>
                <Left>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')}>
                      <Icon name="ios-arrow-round-back" 
                      style={{paddingLeft:10, right:8, fontSize: 50}}/>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    </Left>
                    <Body>
                <Text style={{right: 45, fontSize: 19, fontFamily: 'SourceSansPro-SemiBold' }}>Photo</Text>
                </Body>
            </Header> 
            <Content>
                <View style={{borderTopWidth: 1, borderTopColor: '#eae5e5', shadowOpacity: 10}}>
                <Left> 
                    <Image style={{borderRadius: 75, height: 32, width: 32, right: 145, top: 10}}
                    source={require('../../images/outfit2.png')}/>
                        <Text style={{ color: '#000',bottom: 18, right: 101, fontSize: 15, fontFamily: 'Roboto-Medium'}}>outfit</Text>
                </Left> 
                </View>
                <View style={{borderTopWidth: 1, borderTopColor: '#eae5e5'}}>
                    <Image resizeMethod="resize"

                    // put here from what is selected from profilescreen
                    source={{ }}

                    style={{height:350, width:null, flex:1}}/>
                    </View>
```

This is the screen I want to send the image into the source from profilescreen.

Comment: Use this: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux

Comment: what are you using for navigation from one screen to another screen ??

Comment: I'm using Drawer Navigator for now. I did have stack navigator but i chose to incorporate it in my code later in my code

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters to routes.

In your case you can use below code:

```
<TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={() => {
                                      this.props.navigation.navigate('IndivPhoto', {
                                        /* image params go here */
                                      });
                                    }}>

</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: I've read up on params but im confused on how im supposed to configure my params from a selected image @sdn404 im sorry if im a little dense